# Are there any limits of re-downloading applications from appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I've got an application on my iPhone which was free when I installed it and now it became paid application. One day I accidentally deleted it from device and then was able to download it from Appstore for free (as I "had the previous version" of that app).

So now I just wonder are there limits for that (number of devices I can do that on, any time limits etc)?

**Edit:** The only thing that I managed to find so far is the following paragraph in iTunes Store ["Terms and Conditions"](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html):

> Solely as an accommodation to you,
>   some Products may be redownloaded for
>   use in accordance with the Usage
>   Rules. Not all Products are eligible
>   for this accommodation or may be
>   available at any given time. Apple
>   shall have no liability to you in the
>   event that a previously downloaded
>   Product becomes unavailable for
>   redownload. Once a Product is
>   downloaded, it is your responsibility
>   not to lose, destroy, or damage it,
>   and Apple shall not be liable to you
>   if you do so.

So is it a guaranteed behavior at all?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as its the same app, then you should be able to do this as many times as needed. Also, once you have that app, you have it even if the price changes, goes from free to paid or vice versa.

One thing that I have seen happen in the app store, is developers releasing a whole new version of their app, and naming it differently,  launching it differently. A perfect example of it is Tweetie. When they went to version 2, he re-released it as a new app (Tweetie 2), therefore making anyone who wanted to get the new one to have to pay (even if they paid for the first). Then, that app was converted to free and changed to Twitter for iPhone, but if you bought Tweetie 2, you just got an update that changed it.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... But have you any "official" prooflink?

Answer (score 0):

> "Not all Products are eligible for
>   this accommodation."

I really think this is just them covering themselves for unforeseen circumstances, but the truth is you should never have to worry about getting charged again for the same exact app (free updates included). The only real risk is if the app gets pulled or the dev removes it. I have personally re-downloaded hundreds of apps, so you can trust me.

In contrast, downloading music from iTunes is not the same. Each download will cost you.

Comment: I ask you the same as he asked to the the other, do you have any prooflink? would be nice..

Comment: If they charged you for every download of an app, how would you take advantage of universal apps that run on both iPad & iPhone/iPod? What about folks that have an iPhone and an iPod? What about folks who get a new phone? Technically iTunes could transfer these apps back and forth between devices without downloading a second time from Apple, but that is a HUGE pain in the butt compared to just simply allowing multiple downloads. Apple would never consider creating THAT much friction for AppStore shoppers. This is how Apple works. It's only like that for music cuz of stubborn, greedy musicians.

Comment: As for a proof-link, this image is pretty self-explanatory; it happens whenever you download an app after you've previously purchased it; even on iTunes - http://cl.ly/4Zhr